# C# Windows Form Application - How to take the users input from text boxes

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm confused on what I'm supposed to use to get a users input.
I have 2 TextBoxes and a Button and I want to take what the user enters in those 2 TextBoxes and use it to calculate the total when the button is pushed.
I already have 3 variables declared: one for 1st input, one for the 2nd input, and one for the total of the two.

```
double length;
double width;
double area;

area =((length*length)+(width)(width));
```

I have this code inside of an event handler that will calculate the area when the Button is clicked. C# is new for me, I remember in Java you can use a scanner but I'm not sure what you can use here.

Comment: you will need to reference the textbox object and it's .text property

Comment: You need to get the names of the three textboxes and parse the `.Text` property from the first two to `double` then `txtArea.Text = area.ToString();`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `TextBox` control has a [`Text` property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.windows.forms.textbox?view=netframework-4.8). You would simply reference that to get the value out of the `TextBox`.

Note that in the following example, I'm making assumptions about the names of your controls since you didn't provide them.

```
private void CalculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   string lengthString = LengthTxt.Text;
   string widthString = WidthTxt.Text;
}
```

You'll notice that the `Text` property returns a `string`. You'll need to parse that into a number to do the actual calculations. By using, for example, [`Double.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=netframework-4.8) or [`Double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8).

Since you're taking user input, you should use [`Double.TryParse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.tryparse?view=netframework-4.8). A `TextBox` will take any `string`, after all. Not just `string`s that parse to a `double`.

```
private void CalculateBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
   if (!double.TryParse(LengthTxt.Text, out double length))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the length.");
      return;
   }
   if (!double.TryParse(Width.Text, out double width))
   {
      MessageBox.Show("Please enter a number for the width.");
      return;
   }
}
```

Comment: `.TryParse()` only when handling User input.

Comment: Fair enough. Edited to use `TryParse` instead.

Comment: Can you please explain why you need to parse and what it exactly does. Still having trouble with it, this is what I tried so far:              double area;
            double length;
            double width;

area.Text = Convert.ToString(Convert.ToInt32(length.Text) *Convert.ToInt32(width.Text));

Comment: You have to parse it because a `TextBox` accepts any string. What happens if your user types `"Two"` into the `TextBox`. Or `"This is not a number"`? Using `Convert.ToInt32` or just trying to parse with something like `int.Parse` or `double.Parse` will throw an exception if the input does not represent a number. `TryParse` will return a bool, indicating if the operation was successful. This allows you to handle invalid user input more gracefully.

Answer (score 0):

Click on one of the box and you should see the properties tab on the bottom right. Search for the (Name) property under "Design" and set a name such as "length". In the EventHandler, get the string value with (the name of your box).Text and you can use a method such as Int32.Parse(string) to convert it to an int.